# Access angularJs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application in AngularJS where to move between routes I'm using $state.

In my app.js I put it as follows:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');    

    $stateProvider.state('home', {

        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });
})
```

So from what I can understand, every time you go to the path "home" home.html load the template and HomeCtrl controller.

My controller would be like this:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope,$state,$rootScope, $ionicPlatform) {

    $scope.jugador= $rootScope.players;

    $scope.newMatch = function() {
        $rootScope.item_position = 0;
        $rootScope.data = {
            "code_match": ''
        };

        ($rootScope.players)?[]:new Array();    
        $state.go('create');    
    }
})
```

If I call to the newMatch function, it works perfectly, but if I want to access the variable which I declare before this function called $scope.jugador only will access the first time, once controller is loaded, the next times I want to access to the controller, only could access to the function, not to the variables inside the controller

I tried adding a ng-init="init()" in the template. So, every time that I access to the HTML, should call this function but not, only access this function the first time I load the template. If I go through $state.go('home') dont enter to the variable.

What can be the cause?

Thanks!

Comment: What's `($rootScope.players)?[]:new Array(); ` supposed to do? - `$scope.jugador` is a _reference_ to `$rootScope.players`, so any changes yo do on one of them will be reflected in the other.

Comment: @Josh, I'm using $scope.jugador to use the variable on my template, for this reason every time that I access to the route home.html I want to load on $scope.jugador the content of $rootScope.players, but it only occurs the first time, the rest of times only can access to the function startMatch